# ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string but no extra characters in date

Tags: sql, oracle

In a query I am trying to run, the following where clause is throwing me error "ORA-01830":

```
where to_date(invoice_date,'mm/dd/yy') >  current_date - INTERVAL '5' YEAR
```

The invoice_date column is formatted as 'mm/dd/yy' and when I perform the following query it runs successfully without any errors:

```
select to_date(invoice_date,'mm/dd/yy')
from mytable
```

The invoice_date column clearly doesn't have any other extra characters that I am missing so curious why I am getting this error.

Comment: What's the data type of `invoice_date` and what does it contain?

Comment: How many rows `mytable` contains? Did you check all of them with your second query?

Comment: invoice_date is a varchar.  Mytable contains over 35 million rows and yes I see no error in any rows of the second query.

Comment: You likely have a value within mytable.invoice_date that cannot be formatted to date. I realize it's 35M+ rows, but if you just do a select to_date(invoice_date,'mm/dd/yy') from mytable; query, do you get the error?

Comment: @fleetmack, no I do not get the error.  I queried mytable to see if there were any deviations in how the date is reported, but not seeing anything.  Maybe there is a space or something that could be altering my query

Comment: the space issue is a possibility. Perhaps adding an rtrim to your invoce_date will help?  to_date(rtrim(invoice_date),'mm/dd/yy')

Comment: What is some example output of the `invoice_date`? Does it include the timestamp?